# convert tuple types to decay types

Tags: c++, c++17, stdtuple

I'm playing with C++17, and I have a `std::tuple` of `const &T` types. For ex:

```cpp
template <typename... members>
auto make_cr_tuple(members const &...args) -> decltype(auto) {
    return std::make_tuple(std::cref(args)...);
}

int main() {
    std::string s;
    int i = 0;
    auto crt = make_cr_tuple(s, i); // std::tuple<const std::string &, const int &>
}
```

I would like a way to declare a tuple of each of the value types, removing the const and reference qualifiers. For ex, maybe something like this:

```cpp
    using decayed = decayed_tuple<decltype(crt)>::type
```

I think I could possibly use something like this, but it's not enough.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct decayed_tuple {
    using type = decltype(std::apply(std::make_tuple, T{}));
};
```

Obviously this doesn't work because `make_tuple` is an unresolved overloaded function.

Really I need `std::make_tuple<???>`, but I don't know how to get the types from `T` to the template pack. Note that I'm assuming `T` is default constructible here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can declare (no definition needed) a function as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto decay_types (std::tuple<Ts...> const &)
   -> std::tuple<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Ts>>...>;
```

and use it through `std::declval()` and `decltype()`.

Maybe you can also add an `using` alias to simplify the work

```
template <typename T>
using decay_tuple = decltype(decay_types(std::declval<T>()));
```

A full example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto decay_types (std::tuple<Ts...> const &)
   -> std::tuple<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Ts>>...>;

template <typename T>
using decay_tuple = decltype(decay_types(std::declval<T>()));

int main()
 {
   using T1 = std::tuple<int const &, long const &, long long const &>;
   using T2 = decay_tuple<T1>;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<T2, std::tuple<int, long, long long>>, "!");
 }
```

Comment: That's perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. I forget you can just declare the function without defining it, since we're not actually calling it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html), this is a short one-liner (as always):

```
template <typename Tuple>
using decayed_tuple = mp_transform<std::decay_t, Tuple>;
```

Comment: Wow that's awesome, thanks. I'd like to implement this using `std::` only, but this is a good answer. Perhaps I'll peek at the source.